# React: Input doesn't reflect change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple list made in React with creation/delete/update function. I have a problem in the update, where when I modify the input, the input changes the value, but in the console.log I see the same array updating with no changes made.

**Normally after the update the new list should be updated with the new changes, which is not the case. Instead in the new array, I have `name: undefined` Did I miss something ?**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

export default () => {

  const initialList = [
    {
      id: "a",
      name: "John",
    },
    {
      id: "b",
      name: "Eric"
    },
    {
      id: "c",
      name: "Jonathan"
    },
  ];

  const [list, setList] = React.useState(initialList);
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("");

  function handleChangeUpdate(id) {
    const newList = list.map((item) => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        const updatedItem = {
            ...item,
          };
   
        return updatedItem;
      }
      return item;
    });
 
    setList(newList);
    console.log(newList);
  }
 
  return (
    <div>                
        <ul >             
            <div>
                {list.map((item) => (                                                                    
                    <li key={item.id}>                      
                    <input className="form-control" onChange={()=> handleChangeUpdate(item.id)} defaultValue={item.name}></input>
                    </li>
                    ))}                   
            </div>               
        </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never update the name of the item, just copy the existing item by returning

```
    const updatedItem = {
        ...item,
      };

    return updatedItem;
```

If you 1) pass the updated value to `handleChangeUpdate` and 2) use that value to change the name of the matching item, it works:

```js
const F = () => {

  const initialList = [
    {
      id: "a",
      name: "John",
    },
    {
      id: "b",
      name: "Eric"
    },
    {
      id: "c",
      name: "Jonathan"
    },
  ];

  const [list, setList] = React.useState(initialList);
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("");

  function handleChangeUpdate(id, value) {
    const newList = list.map((item) => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        const updatedItem = {
            ...item,
            name: value
          };
   
        return updatedItem;
      }
      return item;
    });
 
    setList(newList);
    console.log(newList);
  }
 
  return (
    <div>                
        <ul >             
            <div>
                {list.map((item) => (                                                                    
                    <li key={item.id}>                      
                    <input className="form-control" onChange={(e)=> handleChangeUpdate(item.id, e.target.value)} defaultValue={item.name}></input>
                    </li>
                    ))}                   
            </div>               
        </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<F />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: It works! I'm still a complete beginner regarding React/js so, my bad. Thank you very much. I needed to pass an actual value for the `updatedItem` which in my case was empty.

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing anything in the `updatedItem` object. You are spreading the exact same fields from `item` into the new object, without modifying any key. So there'll be no changes

Comment: I tried to put `item.id=id` and `item.name=name` and didn't work

Comment: @AlyaKra do you wish to update the ``name`` state?

Comment: Yes. But it's alright I managed to solved it thanks to the post above.

Comment: As a controlled element you should swap out defaultValue for value aswell

Comment: @Steve Tomlin The problem with `value` is that it didn't want to change at at, like the input was bloqued, so by trying `defaultValue ` it worked. I have no idea.